# Selenium .net SelectElement Options, what is the Proper datatype?

Tags: c#, selenium

Trying to encapsulate this code into a function and pass out the list of options from a dropdown, but can’t figure out the correct data type.

```
public static ?? GetSelectListByID(string elementID)
{
    var mySelectElm = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id(elementID));
    var mySelect = new SelectElement(mySelectElm);
    var options = mySelect.Options;
    return options;
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Doesn't work if you use ```object```?

Comment: If you use the debugger you should see the concrete type of "options"

Comment: It's running as a unit test Morvader so the debugger does not recognize break points.

Comment: gabsferriera: I did try Object, but then it loses many of the attributes available - like count and text. Thanks both!

Comment: FYI. Hovering over the 'options' variable gave it as "(local variable) System.Collections.Generic.IList<IWebElements> options" We did try to return it as an IWebElements, but it would not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using `var` instead of the specific data types. This works for me.

```
public static IList<IWebElement> GetSelectListByID(string elementID)
{
    IWebElement mySelectElm = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id(elementID));
    SelectElement mySelect = new SelectElement(mySelectElm);
    return mySelect.Options;
}
```

Comment: Thanks JeffC! Saw this after my post below!

Comment: Great. Please make sure that you accept an answer so the question gets marked as answered. Thanks!

Comment: "I'm not sure why you are using var". `var` was introduced in `C# 3` They are implicitly typed local variable, the compiler determines the type.

Comment: @JamieR That explains what `var` is, not why it was used. I know what it is. It makes code less clear and bugs harder to find. There are some good, valid uses of `var` but, IMHO, this isn't one of them. The only thing you gain by using `var` is having to type less... kinda... but with modern editors that autocomplete everything that isn't a factor. Case in point... if the OP hadn't used `var` in this case and had specifically typed the return, he wouldn't have had this issue.

Comment: `var` is not the issue! when calling a method you should know the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
The questions from gabsferrira and Morvader gave me the hints I needed.
The 'options' variable I used is of type : "(local variable) System.Collections.Generic.IList options". 
So I did an include of "using System.Collections.Generic;" and passed it out as

```
public static IList<IWebElement> GetSelectListByID(string elementID)
```

Ta da!

Thanks!